# Cant install Crypt_GPG on xampp windows

Tags: php, windows, xampp, pear, pyrus

I used the command
`php pyrus.phar install pear/Crypt_GPG` to install Crypt_GPG in xampp in windows. 
But it is showing the follwoing dependency error

> Pyrus version
>   2.0.0a4 SHA-1: 72271D92C3AA1FA96DF9606CD538868544609A52 Using PEAR installation found at C:\xampp\php\pear Pyrus\Installer\Exception:
>   Dependency validation failed for some packages to ins tall,
>   installation aborted  Pyrus\Dependency\Exception:
>   pear.php.net/Crypt_GPG can optionally use PHP exten sion "posix"
>   Pyrus\Dependency\Exception: Cannot install pear.php.net/Crypt_GPG on
>   Windows

The pear page https://pear.php.net/package/Crypt_GPG says posix is an optional dependendy and also posix cant be installed in windows. It also says that Crypt_GPG can be installed in windows. See bottom of the page.

Is there anyway i can get pass this error and install Crypt_GPG on php in xampp in windows?

Answer (score 0):

Do not use pyrus; it's buggy and not developed anymore.

The original PEAR installer will work fine.